# nodejs - convert one obj to some objects

Tags: node.js, object

I have one obj that I received from the client,

```
const record = {
    "date":"2021-09-20",
    "startAt":"10:00",
    "endAt":"16:00",
    "employeeId": [5,2],<==
    "projectId":[50,48],<==
    "notes":"blahhh"
}
```

I want to convert it to some objects, same details , but I want for example
employeeId 5 worked in two projects, 50 and 48
I want to have two objects with same details but the employeeId is 50 and the projectId : first object with 50 and the sec obj with 48

```
{
    ....
    "employeeId": [5],<== //first emplyee
    "projectId":[50],<== // first project
    ....
}

{
    ....
    "employeeId": [5],//first emplyee
    "projectId":[48], // sec project
    ...
}

{
    ....
    "employeeId": [2],//sec employee
    "projectId":[50], //first project
    ....
}

{
    ....
    "employeeId": [2],//sec employee
    "projectId":[48], //sec project
    ....
}
```

thank you for helping me

Answer (score 0):

You can do for example:

```js
const record = {
  date: "2021-09-20",
  startAt: "10:00",
  endAt: "16:00",
  employeeId: [5, 2],
  projectId: [50, 48],
  notes: "blahhh",
};

const records = record.employeeId
  .map((employeeId) =>
    record.projectId.map((projectId) => ({
      ...record,
      employeeId: [employeeId],
      projectId: [projectId]
    }))
  )
  .flat();

console.log(records);
```

Answer (score 0):

1- Extract all of keys which have array values

```
let arrayKeys = Object.entries(record).filter(([key, value]) => typeof value === 'object' && Array.isArray(value))
```

2- Create your default object with default keys:

```
let defaultObj = Object.entries(record).reduce((obj, [key, value]) => {
  if(!typeof value === 'object' || !Array.isArray(value)) {
    obj[key] = value
  }
  return obj;
}, {})
```

3- Create a function which fill an array with your final objects recursively:

```
function addKeys(array, obj, keys) {
  if(!keys.length) {
    array.push(obj);
    return;  
  }
  let [key, values] = keys.pop();
  values.forEach(val => {
    obj[key] = [val];
    addKeys(array, {...obj}, [...keys])
  });
}
```

Full code:

```js
const record = {
    "date":"2021-09-20",
    "startAt":"10:00",
    "endAt":"16:00",
    "employeeId": [5,2],
    "projectId":[50,48, 60, 70],
    "notes":"blahhh",
    "extraArrayKey": ['a', 'b']
}

let arrayKeys = Object.entries(record).filter(([key, value]) => typeof value === 'object' && Array.isArray(value))

let defaultObj = Object.entries(record).reduce((obj, [key, value]) => {
  if(!typeof value === 'object' || !Array.isArray(value)) {
    obj[key] = value
  }
  return obj;
}, {})

function addKeys(array, obj, keys) {
  if(!keys.length) {
    array.push(obj);
    return;  
  }
  let [key, values] = keys.pop();
  values.forEach(val => {
    obj[key] = [val];
    addKeys(array, {...obj}, [...keys])
  });
}

let output = [];

addKeys(output, defaultObj, arrayKeys)  

console.log(output)
```